# How to create Windows firewall exception in Visual Basic 2005?

Tags: vb.net, firewall

Is there a way I can create Windows firewall exceptions in VB2005? I'm trying to deploy a small app that opens up a few ports so I can connect to them and convert them using VMWare Converter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to this question: [Programmatically add an application to Windows Firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113755/programmatically-add-an-application-to-windows-firewall)

That question is for C#, but since the languages are similar, the techniques should be the same.