# How can I add exception to windows firewall for sql server express using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, firewall

I would like to add exception to windows firewall for sql server express 2008 R2 using C#.

How can I do this?

Scenario:

- I have an application that is installed with Sql Server 2008 express R2 database,
- I would like to add exception to the firewall so other users can connect to the database. (TCP is enabled in the configuration file for the sql express)

How can this be done using C#, I would like to do it automatically on the first application start or in the setup process with custom actions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically add an application to Windows Firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113755/programmatically-add-an-application-to-windows-firewall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

**Windows XP SP2 Firewall Controller**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/WinXPSP2Firewall.aspx

**Controlling Windows Firewall using C# via COM Interop**

http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html

**Netsh Command Syntax for the Netsh Firewall Context**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490617.aspx

Comment: I've just tried example from http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html and I'm getting exception UnauthorizedAccessException, Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: I've figured it out, I need to run app as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this quite easily in C# among other neat things with windows firewall, see this article for more information [Controlling Windows Firewall C#](http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html)

You can also take a look at the answer posted [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/10c6ff4b-701b-4351-a3d8-a716d8831a66).

Comment: Example from the msdn forums is also working nice with Administrator privileges, however example with ports suites me better. Vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20070707110141/http://www.dot.net.nz/Default.aspx?tabid=42&mid=404&ctl=Details&ItemID=8). It wraps up access to the windows firewall API.

Should do the trick.

### EDIT:

Actually this looks better --> [Automating Windows Firewall Settings with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/securitytools/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c)

You should be able to open up the port you want using this

```
1: INetFwOpenPorts ports; 
2: INetFwOpenPort port; 
3: port.Port = 1433; /* port no */
4: port.Name = “Application1”; /*name of the application using the port */
5: port.Enabled =  true; /* enable the port */
6: /*other properties like Protocol, IP Version can also be set accordingly
7: now add this to the GloballyOpenPorts collection */
8: 
9: Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false); 
10: INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType); 
11: ports = (INetFwOpenPorts)mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.GloballyOpenPorts; 
12: 
13: ports.Add(port);
14:
```

Note in Visual Studio, you need to add `NetFwTypeLib COM` reference to your project and also include NetFwTypeLib in your project ( `using NetFwTypeLib;`)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying this example code, but I'm getting message Error 258 Use of unassigned local variable 'port'. Do you have any idea how can I create new object port? What class should I use?

Comment: Just tried with this snippet

Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWOpenPort");
port = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as INetFwOpenPort;

unfortunately, I'm getting NullReferenceException, although all locals are not null.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create inbound firewall rule for sql server 1433 port with multiprofile Domain, Public and Private through C#.

First you have to import a dll from your system “C:\Windows\System32/FirewallAPI.dll”.
Add this DLL to your project reference.
Go to solution explorer in visual studio -> References->Add Reference->click on Browse button near ok and cancel button -> browse path C:\Windows\System32/FirewallAPI.dll and add the dll.

After adding dll use namespace “NetFwTypeLib” in your code like this at above program.
using NetFwTypeLib;

```
   using NetFwTypeLib;
   namespace ConsoleAppTestDemo
   {
    class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
        INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);

        // Let's create a new rule
        INetFwRule2 inboundRule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
        inboundRule.Enabled = true;
        //Allow through firewall
        inboundRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;

        //For all profile
        inboundRule.Profiles = (int)NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_ALL;

        //Using protocol TCP
        inboundRule.Protocol = 6; // TCP
        //Local Port 1433
        inboundRule.LocalPorts = "1433";
        //Name of rule
        inboundRule.Name = "SQLRule";

        // Now add the rule
        INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
        firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(inboundRule);
    }
}
```

}

After that you can check your firewall inbound rule.
[image]

Comment: http://stackoperation.com/create-window-inbound-firewall-rule-for-sql-server-1433-port-through-programmatically/