# Expose WCF service cannot retrieve object through windows firewall

Tags: vb.net, wcf, windows-firewall

I built a WCF service that exposes itself for a web application, it accepts an object and prints the data on the clients machine. Works fine on my development machine, and the service is up and running on any machine i install it on. I can enter ip address in clients machine web browser and see it is running. Problem is when i send the object to the clients machine it returns an error, that sounds like it could be because of the clients windows firewall. Where would i start at to deal with this problem ?

There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.1.168:2202/PrintLabel that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

And the InnerException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: Are you able to view `192.168.1.168:2202` with port number from the client's browser?  If so, it wouldn't seem like a firewall issue.

Comment: Ok so on my Windows XP VM it can able to view the port and locate the service, but not on my Win 7 VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With further research and discussion with people in the community i came to understand that as was mentioned at the bottom of [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) 
"Self-hosted HTTP addressing for WCF is not integrated into the Windows firewall. An exception must be added to the firewall configuration to allow inbound connections using a particular URL. 

But [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113755/programmatically-add-an-application-to-windows-firewall) led me to a page with how to control Windows Firewall through code to enable my WCF self hosted service to accept an object.
This the link below.

http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html

That link was towards the direction i needed, but based on user comments it seemed to have some bugs. A colleague found [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx) and i believe this technique will be the best solution for this scenario.