# Programmatically add an windows service to Windows Firewall (During Installation)

Tags: c#, windows-services, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically add an application to Windows Firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113755/programmatically-add-an-application-to-windows-firewall)

in my solution i have an windows service project and installer to install this service 
How i can add this service to  Windows Firewall During Installation.

Comment: Depending on the deployment project, but [here's a solution for wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/firewall_xsd_firewallexception.htm)

Comment: You should really expand with more details of your problem.. What have you tried? What type of "installer" are you using?

Comment: I don't think this exact duplicate, other issue is about a ClickOnce installer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming we're using a `Visual Studio Installer->Setup Project` - You need an installer class like this inside an assembly that's being installed, and then make sure you add a custom action for the "Primary output" in the install phase.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class AddFirewallExceptionInstaller : Installer
    {
        protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);

            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]);
            OpenFirewallForProgram(Path.Combine(path, "YourExe.exe"),
                                   "Your program name for display");
        }

        private static void OpenFirewallForProgram(string exeFileName, string displayName)
        {
            var proc = Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "netsh",
                        Arguments =
                            string.Format(
                                "firewall add allowedprogram program=\"{0}\" name=\"{1}\" profile=\"ALL\"",
                                exeFileName, displayName),
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    });
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks weston but What do you mean "YourExe.exe" , you mean full path + exe file name

Comment: @tito11 - Sorry, yes you do need the path, please see modifications to code.

Comment: Today you should use: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Application" dir=in action=allow program="C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe" enable=yes` see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=121488