# Windows 8 adding program to firewall exceptions

Tags: c#, windows, firewall

After installation of the program is finished.

For windows 8, I need to problematically (in C#) or via bat script need to an executable to the firewall exception list in Windows 8 for at least outgoing connections,

can someone please advise
I have already seen

> [Programmatically add an application to Windows Firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113755/programmatically-add-an-application-to-windows-firewall)

but this is OS specific and not for windows 8

Comment: It hasn't really changed in Windows 8.  You can still use the [netsh firewall shell commands](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709) to configure firewall exceptions.  And in order to run these shell commands you must do it from a process which is elevated to administrator privileges.

Answer (score -4):

Go to the Windows 8 Start screen and simply type Firewall and opens the configuration.

In the menu choose New Rule, then you'll be able to add exception for your C#

Hope this helps